# openmp shared array

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

i have two nasted for(s) that work with shared arrays and shared boolean flag, i know that it might be a collisions while trying to write into array but if i make thoose sections critical i will lose all benefits of paralleling this. Is there any options how can i avoid this and still work in parallel? thanks

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
#pragma omp for schedule (guided)
            for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
                {
                    if(cluster[i*N+j]!=0)
                    {
                        inner_set[i]=1;// Critical???
                        inner_set[j]=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outter_set[i]=1;
                    }
                }
            }
}

do
{
    isChanged=false;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule (guided)      
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                if(inner_set[i]!=0)
                {
                    for (int j=0; j<N;j++)
                    {
                        if(i!=j && outter_set[j]!=0)
                        {
                            if(dis[i*N+j]<Dis)
                            {
                                isChanged=true;
                                inner_set[i]=0;//critical???
                                outter_set[i]=1;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


        }
}while(isChanged);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the parallelism, is along the **index i** and j runs from **(i+1)->N** for all threads.
So what you think as **critical** is not. The next line i.e.

```
inner_set[j] = 1
```

is actually overwritten by all threads.

you need **#pragma omp critical** for that line.

The second loop is good for parallelism again for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you very much. If i got it right, everywhere is something chenged through index i is NOT critical in this implementation, but what is changed via index j is critical? may be it would better idea to use locks? again thank you.

Comment: Yes. To debug, run the code in serial mode and then parallel and compare the results. If it works, vote for the ans so that any1 can refer as a solution to the problem.